# WHO Essential Medicines vs Essential Medicines for Children

Tags: medicine

Per the WHO (World Health Organization), there are a list of "Essential Medicines" such as those listed on their Wikipedia page.

1. Is there a database link for this directly other than Wikipedia?
2. What is the difference between the "Children" list and the regular list. Is one a complete superset of the other? I noticed the "Children's" list is much larger.

I would like to make an **open** JSON database of some sort regarding a more easily accessible and organized way of accessing this data in a Postgres database or something. What do you know like this that exists?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHO_Model_List_of_Essential_Medicines
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHO_Model_List_of_Essential_Medicines_for_Children

Comment: Wikipedia links to ressources: this is the first references of your linked article: https://www.who.int/medicines/services/essmedicines_def/en/ - it should contain all information that is needed, though arguably not in an easily parseable format

Comment: Neither list is a superset of the other.  The children's list is longer but notably lacks [medicines for reproductive health and perinatal care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHO_Model_List_of_Essential_Medicines#Medicines_for_reproductive_health_and_perinatal_care).